# Plotting text in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a graph something similar to [this](http://www.dataists.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/rank_scatter1.png):

For that, I have written the following function in python

```
def plot_graph_perf(dataset):

        #TODO: Give labels as power ranges in spaces of 1000

        plotter = ['0',
                        '1200000-10', '1200000-14', '1200000-18',
                        '1200000-2', '1200000-22', '1200000-26', '1200000-30',
                        '1200000-34', '1200000-38', '1200000-42', '1200000-46',
                        '1200000-6',
                        '1600000-10', '1600000-14',
                        '1600000-18', '1600000-2', '1600000-22',
                        '1600000-26', '1600000-30', '1600000-34',
                        '1600000-38', '1600000-42', '1600000-46',
                        '1600000-6',
                        '2000000-10', '2000000-14',
                        '2000000-18', '2000000-2', '2000000-22',
                        '2000000-26', '2000000-30', '2000000-34',
                        '2000000-38', '2000000-42', '2000000-46',
                        '2000000-6',
                        '2400000-10', '2400000-14',
                        '2400000-18', '2400000-2', '2400000-22',
                        '2400000-26', '2400000-30', '2400000-34',
                        '2400000-38', '2400000-42', '2400000-46',
                        '2400000-6' ,
                        '800000-10', '800000-14',
                        '800000-18', '800000-2', '800000-22',
                        '800000-26', '800000-30', '800000-34',
                        '800000-38', '800000-42', '800000-46',
                        '800000-6' ]


        x_axis_labels = dataset[1]

        x=[a for a in range(len(x_axis_labels))]
        y_axis_labels =  dataset[0]
        y=[a for a in range(len(y_axis_labels))]

        width = 0.1
        plt.figure
        plt.plot(plotter, color = 'g')
        plt.tight_layout(pad=1, h_pad=4, w_pad=None)
        plt.xticks(x,x_axis_labels, rotation='vertical')
        plt.yticks(y,y_axis_labels, rotation='horizontal')
        plt.xlabel('Power')
        plt.ylabel('perf')
        plt.title(file + ' | (Power)')
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.set_size_inches(28.5,10.5)
        plt.savefig('watt' + '.png',bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5,dpi=100)
        plt.clf()
```

Where dataset is two dimensional list something like this

```
dataset = [[],[]]
```

each sublist containing same number of elements as `plotter`.

I plotted `dataset[0]` and `dataset[1]` as `y` and `x` respectively, but was unable to plot the string values in `plotter`.

Can you please shed some light and help me plot the `plotter` values on the graph.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the text function?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand which three parameters to give in.

Comment: Looks like this: [Fonts demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fonts_demo_kw.html)

Comment: This is what I tried:         `plt.text(x_axis_labels,y_axis_labels,plotter, fontsize=10)`
and I get the error:
`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`
Should i iterate over the list?

Comment: Yeah `text` has to be called separately each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call the `text` function for each word separately:

```
words = list("abcdefg")
xs = np.random.randint(0,10,len(words))
ys = np.random.randint(0,10,len(words))

for x, y, s in zip(xs,ys,words):
    plt.text(x,y,s)
```

[image: letters]

Comment: Thanks for that!
i've done that.
but there seems to be another error:
ValueError: width and height must each be below 32768

Comment: in this line:
`plt.savefig('watt' + '.png',bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5,dpi=100)`